# Getting value from text field in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

```
      print $q->textfield(
            -name => 'UserName',
            -value =>'JACOB',
            -size  => 30,
            -maxlength =>50,
          ); 
     my $User =$q->param('UserName');
```

This code does not read the value from the textfield. 
What is the issue in this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your understanding of CGI, and the way you structure your web apps.

In its most simple form, a CGI script is called with some parameters (usually either a GET query string, or some POST data), which the CGI module can extract for you. Once that is done, you can print some response to that request.

A more complicated form figures out from the HTTP method and/or the available parameters if it was already called by itself, or if the user wasn't there before. In that case, usually a blank form is printed out. When the user submits that form back to the script, the script can extract the wanted data from the query:

> **User:** Hey, take this request:
>
> ```
> GET /script.pl
> ```
>
> **Script1:** Oh, no parameters ☹ … OK, please receive this:
>
> ```
> Content-type: text/html
>
> <form action="/script.pl" method="post">
>   <input name="foo" type="text"/>
>   <input name="age" type="text"/>
>   <button type="submit>Submit</button>
> </form>
> ```
>
> **User:** Ok, let me fill out that form:
>
> ```
> POST /script.pl
>
> foo=Foofle+Barbar&age=42
> ```
>
> **Script2:** Oh nice, you gave me the `foo` parameter. Let me respond with:
>
> ```
> Content-type: text/html
>
> <p>Great, your name is <i>Foofle Barbar</i>! You are 42 years old!</p>
> ```

HTTP, and by extension CGI, is *stateless* – you have to carry all the important information around in each request. Also, each time your CGI script is invoked, you get a new instance of that script (unless you use certain technologies).

Therefore, you should probably write code like

```
if (my $User = $q->param('UserName')) {
  print "hello, $User!\n";
} else {
  print $q->textfield( ... );
}
```

or even better:

```
if ($q->request_method() eq 'POST') 
  print "hello, ", $q->param('UserName'), "!\n";
else {
  print $q->textfield( ... );
}
```

A common technique is to include hidden fields that are transmitted with each request. This can be used to figure out the state of your script. But that is really what Cookies are for.